# How to communicate saved value of custom type lightning-record-picker edit panel to lightning-datatable

Tags: datatable, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I have a Custom Type in an LWC lightning-datatable that accepts record ids. As such, the edit panel is a lightning-record-picker. However, when I make a change through the lightning-record-picker, it successfully gets the new record and stores the correct new record id, but this does not display on the datatable, and it seems the new value is not being correctly communicated back to the datatable.
My question is: how can I correctly communicate the new value back to the parent datatable? What event should be fired and what is its structure?

Currently I have tried firing the onchange event manually like this:

```
import {api, LightningElement} from 'lwc';

export default class DataTableLookupEditor extends LightningElement
{
    _value = null;
    @api
    get value()
    {
        return this._value;
    }

    set value(val)
    {
        this._value = val;
    }

    @api
    typeAttributes;
    @api
    required;
    @api
    objectApiName;

    handleChange(event)
    {
        this._value = event.detail.recordId;

        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change', {
            bubbles: true,
            composed: true,
            detail: {
                value: this._value,
            },
        }));
    }


    @api
    get validity()
    {
        return this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-picker').reportValidity;
    }

    @api
    showHelpMessageIfInvalid()
    {

    }

    @api
    focus()
    {
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-picker').focus();
    }
}
```

Further, I have tried this same setup instead using a lightning-combobox, and there are no issues.